# Laravel's UUID (introduced in 9.3) throwing some errors for Users

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum, laravel-controller

I recently decided to upgrade to Laravel 9.3 (from 9.1). I wanted to take advantage of the UUID introduced by 9.3 and get rid of my custom UUID trait. So now my models use:

`use HasUuids;`

So far so good. But I noticed that my `Users` table was using an autoincrement PK so I decided to use UUID in there as well. To do so I changed the migration to be:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        ...
```

But now when I try to register a new user:

```
$hashedPassword = Hash::make($data->password);

        $userToRegister = new RegisterUserData(
            $data->name,
            $data->email,
            $hashedPassword,
        );

        $user = User::create($userToRegister->toArray());
        return $user->getAuthToken();
```

I'm getting back the following error:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'tokenable_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `expires_at`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (auth_token, bbd7ff53780a9a4e1e922a03e7c7bd2ae23f8043ba809d19392cf1e9f91a357c, [\"*\"], ?, 97c75f9d-e2cd-4d40-8fb2-8947854dd89d, Domain\\Shared\\Models\\User, 2022-11-19 02:39:44, 2022-11-19 02:39:44))",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-be/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
```

It is a warning so the User is being still created but don't know where this is coming from. Furthermore, if I try to login that existing user I'm getting something similar:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'tokenable_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `expires_at`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (auth_token, 32a157db020baca42fce009373d807d9154be108505792a5138dbfa457c4a631, [\"*\"], ?, 97c75ed4-4264-4875-a3b6-6985d3080943, Domain\\Shared\\Models\\User, 2022-11-19 02:39:01, 2022-11-19 02:39:01))"
}
```

the login function in the controller is:

```
public function login(UserData $userData): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            if (!Auth::attempt($userData->toArray())) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => "invalid credentials",
                ])->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }

            $user = User::where('email', $userData->email)->first();

            return response()
                ->json([ 'data' => $user->getAuthToken()])
                ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                // todo: log the actual error but return a custom one to avoid giving away system details.
                'message' => $th->getMessage()
            ], Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

any idea what's going on?

Comment: Does your `personal_access_token` using `morphs()` when defining `tokenable_id` ?

Comment: can you add codes from your ``personal_access_tokens`` migration file? Possible there length is set for the ``tokenable_id`` column.

Comment: I got it guys, thanks for your help. The issue is that the column `tokenable_id` was created initially as type `int`, and that column seems to store the ID of the user for which the token is being generate, but now the ID for a user is of type `UUID` (`varchar`) not `int`, therefore I had to run a new migration to update the column type